# How do I get the name of the form from the onSubmit event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events

My form looks like this:

```
    <form name="test" action="" method="post" onSubmit="submitCRMSearch(event);return false;">
    <table class='borderless'>
        <tr><td>TERM:</td><td><input type="text" name="term" value=""></td></tr>
        <tr><td>START:</td><td><input type="text" name="start" value=""></td></tr>
        <tr><td>LIMIT:</td><td><input type="text" name="limit" value=""></td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td class='right'><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

...and my JavaScript function looks like this:

```
function submitCRMSearch(e){
    var target = e.target
    var string = "\n";
    $.each(target,function(k,v){
        string += v.name + " = " + v.value + "<br>\n";
    })
    string += 
    string += "\n";
    $("#output").html(string);
}
```

I can easily get the names of the input elements and their values form the target property of the event. But how do I get the name of the form object that sent the event to begin with?

Comment: um, `target.name`?

Comment: using `this.name`?

Comment: for jquery `$(v).attr('name')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously its `target.name` since `onSubmit` is attached to the `form` tag making it the `target`.